# Weird error with WSL when running python script using VS

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a python script using VS code and I'm getting a weird error when I'm using the WSL bash. I included an image of the error

[image]

What is `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('` referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the Python extension thinks you're running under Windows which suggests you manually set your terminal to WSL. Please make sure to use the [Remote - WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) as that will make VS Code and all extensions treat your environment as WSL/Linux instead of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means there is a parenthesis that needs to be escaped.

Try escaping it like `Program Files \(x86\)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean exactly by escaping it? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I guess my question is where should I do this? Because in my code I don't have Program Files (x86)

Comment: @user10796158 I’m not sure what code you were running to get this error.  Was it the code on screen or in the vscode terminal?  Just paste the code that gave you the error here.

Comment: @user10796158 just search through your code for any parenthesis in a string and put a backslash in front of them